# AnalysisException PySpark: Cannot resolve function ST_LengthSpheroid

Tags: python, pyspark

I am using PySpark with Apache Sedona to make my geo related stuff:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark-geopandas").\
getOrCreate()

config = SedonaContext.builder() .\
    config('spark.jars.packages',
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.4_2.12:1.5.1,'
           'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.5.1-28.2'). \
    getOrCreate()
sedona = SedonaContext.create(config)
sc = sedona.sparkContext
```

.. then

```
final_df.createOrReplaceTempView("final_df")
    query = """select *, ST_LineStringFromText(final_df.geometry, ',') as geom, 
ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_LineStringFromText(final_df.geometry, ',')) as len from final_df"""
        final_df = sedona.sql(query)
```

.. and I get following error:

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_ROUTINE] 
Cannot resolve function `ST_LengthSpheroid` on search path
```

Why ?

if I change **ST_LengthSpheroid** to **ST_Length** - all works, no errors..

regards

Comment: What version of Sedona are you using? Check with `pip show apache-sedona`. According to the [documentation](https://sedona.apache.org/1.5.0/api/sql/Function/#st_lengthspheroid) this function is only available from version 1.4.1, maybe that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance put another old sedona-spark jar in `SPARK_HOME/jars`? If so, this will lead to this problem as it conflicts with the jar you specified in SedonaContext: org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.4_2.12:1.5.1